# Yaml Python 2.7 and Python 3.7 compatible dump and load with unicode characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7, python-unicode, pyyaml

I'm having issues loading/dumping yaml files with PyYaml that need to be compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.

For Python 3 dumping/ Python 2 loading, I found a solution:

```
import yaml
data = {"d": ""}
with open(file_path, "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f, allow_unicode=True)
```

This produces a yaml file with this line:

```
d:
```

If I try to load this file with Python 2:

```
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    y = yaml.safe_load(f)
    print(y["d"])
```

I get the following output:

But now if I try to dump a file with Python 2, I tried:

```
data = {"d": u""}
with open(file_name, "w") as f:
   yaml.dump(f)
```

which produces a yaml file:

```
d: "\uD83D\uDE0B"
```

I also tried:

```
data = {"d": u"".encode("utf-8")}
with open(file_name, "w") as f:
   yaml.dump(f)
```

which produces a yaml file:

```
d: !!python/str "\uD83D\uDE0B"
```

In both cases, if I load with Python 3:

```
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    y = yaml.load(f)
```

then `y["d"]` is `'\ud83d\ude0b'`
which cannot be used as is.

I found out I could do something like

```
y["d"].encode("utf-16", "surrogatepass").decode("utf-16")
```

but that seems like an overkill.

So what's the solution for dumping a file with Python 2 that is readable and properly interpreted in Python 3?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the encoding in the yaml.dump? see Python 3 support session of https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: I tried encoding="utf-8", which is the default, encoding=None and a few others I think, without success. Always ends up as a unicode

Comment: After reading through the PyYaml docs again I think it is expected behaviour and you cannot avoid doing some conversion after loading it in Python 3. It is because the emoji was treated as a unicode object in Python 2 and was treated so when dumping, it will not be converted back as an emoji automatically when you load it as a string in Python 3.

Comment: But do you think there's a smart way using yaml classes to actually achieve that?

Comment: Maybe you can write your own Dumper and Loader? Or try adding constructors, represented or resolvers of them. Check out that session in their docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding a constructor for this.
I add it to a custom loader, so I do `self.add_constructor`, but it's the same at the yaml level, easier to illustrate with that.

`yaml.add_constructor("tag:yaml.org,2002:python/str", unicode_constructor)`

```
def unicode_constructor(loader, node):
    scalar = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    return scalar.encode("utf-16", "surrogatepass").decode("utf-16")
```

This works for Python2 dump/ Python 3 load

and doesn't affect Python 3 dump/ Python 2 or 3 load